# Access an NSString from a C-Style Function Outside of The Function

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, nsstring, global-variables

I have a C style function inside the 'Delegate.m' file in an iOS XCode project. The function is declared at the top of the file after a few '#import's and the '@implementation' etc. Inside that C function an NSString is declared and a value assigned to it (a URL). In the:

> application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

method, still in the 'Delegate.m' file I am wanting to open that URL in a UIWebView. I have all the code for that, but, on the line:

> NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

I get an error saying:

> 'urlString' undeclared

In the C function where 'urlString' is declared I get a warning saying:

> Unused variable 'urlString'

I am declaring the NSString in the C function like so:

> NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/%d",myInt];

I have some understanding of 'variable scope', but I'm just starting out with programming so I'm not too sure. Something has obviously gone wrong and would be really grateful for any help.

Many Thanks.

Comment: C function can be quickly converted to a objective-C class member function in the App delegate which returns a NSString. It would then get called from "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" Any reason why you cannot do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the urlString variable only exists within its scope, which is the C style function you mention. It does not exist/live outside its scope (the function).

You can make the scope of the variable 'global', by declaring it at the top of your file, right after the imports.

```
NSURL *urlString;
```

Also change the line where you initialize it so that you are not declaring it again:

```
urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/%d",myInt];
```

Comment: Generally, you don't want to do that, though.   Globals quickly become very messy.

Comment: Agreed, global vars are evil and all that. Being the OP a newbie, I thought I'd just provide him with a quick and dirty solution so that he can move on with whatever he's up to.